# Performance Testing of JNLP Swing Application

Tags: java, performance, swing, testing

We have a Swing Application launched via JNLP. This interacts with web services to retrieve and submit data. Entire business logic is in web services.
Our aim is to do a round of performance testing and find out bottlenecks while rendering.

Please advise strategies,  tools and guidelines for testing performance of UI. We do not want to get in to time taken to retrieve data from web services.

Comment: Start with [profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Use JVisualVM. It's a part of JDK installation and helps to determine most of performance bottlnecks. VisualVM can connect to any Java application on your computer and easy to use. I think, the best way for you is using of CPU sampling. But for interpreting of results you should good understand how Swing works. I've already used this tool to find performance problems in legacy code. But in some cases you can find that the performance issue is somewere deep in Swing (for example rendering of large HTML pages is very slow due to performance problems in HTML package of Swing).

Comment: Thanks , let me try Visual VM